# Grandi's series/sequence using a for-loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sequence, series

How can you develop a series/sequence of 100 iterations using a **for-loop** or a **while-loop**?

```
f <- c()
while(length(f) < 100) {
  a <- 1
  f <- c(f, a)
  b <- 0
  f <- c(f, b)
}
print(f)
```

I have the correct output but the input is not correspondent with Grandi's series.

Comment: Can you please specify the last sentence? fyi, `f <- rep(c(1, 0), 50)` would give the same result. I do not see Grandi's series or the geometric series, respectively, in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Grandi's series. I would like to learn how to input it within a loop rather than built-in functions. I can't get my head around how to transform summation operator formulas of sequences within R basically

Comment: Do you want the sum of the first n elements of Grandi's series (for n=1 to 100) or the first 100 elements of Grandi's series?

Comment: The first 100 elements, not the sum of them.

Comment: `for (x in 1:10) print(ifelse(x %% 2 == 1, 1, -1))`.  Or, if you're not tied to a `for` or `while` loop, `sapply(1:10, function(x) ifelse(x %% 2 == 1, 1, -1))`.

Answer (score 2):

Found how:

```
g <- 1
for(i in seq_along(1:100)) {
  g[[i + 1]] <- g[[i]] + (-1)^i
}

g
```